# JPA Hibernate - Entity with @Loader and a function field in select, won't work properly

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cad_paciente")
@Loader(namedQuery = "selectInicial")
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name="selectInicial", 
        query="select p.*, fu_obter_lista_convenios_pac(p.id) as ds_convenio from cad_paciente p where p.id = ?", resultClass = Paciente.class,
        resultSetMapping = "sqlResult")
@SqlResultSetMapping(
          name="sqlResult",
          entities={
            @EntityResult(entityClass = Paciente.class, fields={
                @FieldResult(name="ds_convenio",column="ds_convenio")})})
public class Paciente {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name="id_empresa")
private Integer id_empresa;    

...

@Transient
@Column(name="ds_convenio")
private String ds_convenio;

public String getDs_convenio() {
    return ds_convenio;
}

public void setDs_convenio(String ds_convenio) {
    this.ds_convenio = ds_convenio;
}
```

My Controller method "pacientes.findAll()" won't return "ds_convenio" field with the correct value, listing "null" always in my JSON return.

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the annotation `@Transient` and provide the column as below :

```
@Column(name="ds_convenio")
private String ds_convenio;
```

`@org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient` specifically states to the spring framework that the Object Mapper you are using should not include this value when converting from Java Object to JSON. Also, it means that the value is not to be persisted into the database, which means you could not query over it.

Or if you want to **keep** it as transient itself but **does not require** the value to be serialized then register the object mapper as below :

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper includeTransientObjectMapper() {
    Hibernate5Module hibernate5Module = new Hibernate5Module();
    hibernate5Module.disable(Hibernate5Module.Feature.USE_TRANSIENT_ANNOTATION);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(hibernate5Module);
    return mapper;
}
```

Or in your case since you want the result of the `@NamedNativeQuer` in which you aliased `ds_convenio`, using `@FieldResult` might be required to get the desired result as follows :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cad_paciente")
@Loader(namedQuery = "selectInicial")
@NamedNativeQuery(name="selectInicial", query="select p.*, fu_obter_lista_convenios_pac(p.id) as ds_convenio from cad_paciente p where p.id = ?", resultClass = Paciente.class)
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="Results",
       entities={
           @EntityResult(entityClass=com.acme.Order.class, fields={
               @FieldResult(name="id", column="id"),
               @FieldResult(name="id_empresa", column="id_empresa"),
               ........
       })
public class Paciente {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name="id_empresa")
private Integer id_empresa;    

...

@Transient
@Column(name="ds_convenio")
private String ds_convenio;
```

Read [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-query-native)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to remove Transient but this error appears: 
ERROR: column paciente0_.ds_convenio does not exist

Where do I put this @Bean method?

Comment: @DiegoBolognini If you are seeing this error when removing the transient annotation it means that the field should be kept as transient itself as the column won't be present in the database.Transient fields are values that the end user needs but are usually not present in the db table.If you do not need them in the json you could use the object mapper to enable using transient annotation so that the value is not serialized as well.Just provide the bean in a configuration class.

Comment: @DiegoBolognini I had overlooked your native query so i have updated the answer. It seems your alias column is not getting mapped to your entity correctly, hance the null value.Use `@FieldResult` to map it correctly.

Comment: My java code has been update with the @SqlResultSetMapping ... but without Transient in column = error of column unknown.. with Transient = JSON lists my column as null, always.. columns that are fields in the table, lists fine..

Comment: @DiegoBolognini you need the transient annotation, also you need the mapping as you are using alias name . What is fu_obter_lista_convenios_pac(p.id) ?

Comment: fu_obter_lista_convenios_pac is a function that returns all the insurance mapped to a patient.. what I need is this column returns non-null in my JSON, trought the namedNativeQuery.. is there a way to do it?